# Allowing for more then one "no-value" value in value space

Tags: oop, design-patterns, design-principles

I use a string type for my Id attribute on all my domain abjects. E.g.:

```
public class Person {
    property string Id { get; set; }
    // ... more properties
}
```

no tricks here. `null` represents a "no-value" value, when a new Person is created and before it is persisted, `Id` will remain `null`.

Now there is a discussion to enhance "no-value" space and say that `null`, empty string and white-space strings are all "no-value" values.

I.e. to check if entity is new instead of doing: `if (person.Id == null)` it will become `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(person.Id))`

In my humble opinion this is a smell or a design principle violation, but I can't figure out which one.

**Question:** which (if any) design principle does this decision violate (the decision to allow for more than just `null` to represent no-value value)?

(I think it should be something similar to Occam's razor principle or entropy or KISS, I just not sure)

Comment: Why does the proposed change seem like poor design to you? Anything besides the fact that "no value" will be represented by more than one `Id` value? How does the application currently treat empty or whitespace Id values?

Comment: my draft argument would be - simpler system is better. and system with fewer assumptions is simpler. system that's built on "no-value"=null has one less assumption then system built on "no-value" is one of null or empty string.

Comment: Personally I don't like the idea of having different values in Id that have the same meaning. Where do empty strings and even "white-space string" come from? I would implement the setter performing a clean up of the value or perhaps better: refuse to set values that don't have a meaning (e.g. empty strings). Depends on the context. Again: where do these strings come from? Somewhere from your database? From some file? If it is some hand edited file perhaps your code reading this file should sanitize it. If these values come from a database: why are they there?

Comment: @mdo: even if white-space `Id` does come from outside, I can force it to null in setter, as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does violate the KISS principle. If there is no special need for handling empty strings beside nulls, then why do it? All operations must now check for two values, instead of one. When exploring the DB, a simple SELECT to find "NULL" records, becomes slightly less trivial for no good reason.

Another violated principle is the principle of least surprise - usually people expect only NULL values to represent NULL objects. The design with two special values is less obvious, and less "readable".

If something more should be hidden behind these "second-category-special-objects", then it should be made explicit. Otherwise, it should be trivial to handle empty string input, and store it as NULL to be coherent with the rest of the system.

EDIT:

I've also found another "principle" in Bob Martin's book [Clean code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) - "one word per concept" which is somehow related to this case. Empty string and a NULL are two "words" used for one concept so they clearly violate this guideline.

Comment: I agree with you. I wonder if Occam's razor can be applied here. Essentially we have two alternative systems - in one there is exactly one no-value value, in the other there are two equivalent no-value values. Obviously first system is simpler (hence KISS is satisfied). Although Occam's razor kinda works in the opposite direction though (from observation to theory).

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna go out on a limb and say defining both `null` and `""` as the empty String for your application does not violate any design principles and is not a code smell.  You need to just clearly define the semantics of the field for your purpose, and you have done so (i.e., in your application, but `null` and `""` mean "no value").

You should have tests that ensure behavior is correct for both `null` and `""`.

This is not to say that you also can't make the decision to force all empty strings to null.  That is an equally valid decision.  You would need to have tests that verify that in all cases where you set the "No value", the actual value is null.  You might want to go this way if your persistence layer expects null and only null to indicate no value.

So, in this case, there are no wrong decisions, just decisions.

Comment: well, a simple demonstration of why it might be bad: if it is ok to extend no-value range with one empty sting and infinite number of white-space strings. It should be ok to add any other arbitrary values, e.g. "NO-VALUE", "NV", "Oh!No!" and "this ain't value". On a practical side, no every test that uses that assumption should also have a test for each no-value.

Comment: Your logic is a complete non-sequitur.  How do you go from saying, if only whitespace defines no-value, then non-whitespace defines no value?

Comment: string is an "infinite" set of values. If there is no issue of including empty string and all white-space values in the definition of "no-value" set, then it should be equally ok to further expand that "no-value" set with other pre-determined values of the string set. For example Id is no-value if it is one of { null, "", " ",  "NO-VALUE" }. I do not say that _any_ non-whitespace is no-value. I suggested few fixed values.

Comment: clearly, you want only null.  Still there is a distinction between making an informed decision after analysis and a code smell/bad design principle.

Comment: @THX-1138 - You're falling down a slippery slope fallacy. There are important semantic and conventional differences between whitespace strings and "NO-VALUE", so "NO-VALUE" isn't as appropriate as " " as a member of the no value set. There's no `string.IsNOVALUE` test method in the framework, but there is one for whitespace - this is a clue that there are important differences between them.